# How can i create such a xml hieararcy?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to create dynamic XML hieararchy but still couldn't be successful about it.I tried LinqToXml classes and XML classes but still i couldn't. I want to create such a hierarchy in a loop dynamically.

Create root node

```
<Root></Root>
```

Then add child for it.

```
<Root>
 <Biggest></Biggest>
</Root>
```

Then add child for last added node

```
<Root>
   <Biggest>
      <Bigger>
      </Bigger>
   </Biggest>
</Root>
```

Then go back add another

```
<Root>
   <Biggest>
      <Bigger>
      </Bigger>
      <Another>
      </Another>
  </Biggest>
</Root>
```

Edit: i want to give an example.

```
  XElement root = new XElement("root");
    XElement first = new XElement("first", "value");
    XElement second = new XElement("second", "Value");

    root.Add(first);
    //now how can add second node into first ??
    //I don't want to add second one into first then add it into root.
```

Comment: Seems straight forward. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: What are you trying to do *exactly*? Such structure does not look like it needs a loop at all. Are you using the `Add` method on created elements?

Comment: There is a recurisive method which i want to get value trees into a xmlfile. U can just give an example how to navigate in tree hieararchy and add child elements ..etc

Comment: You can do `root.Add(first);` first and then do `first.Add(second)`. The order in which you do that does not matter. The Xml document is not built like a string, it is a hierarchy of objects - you can add new nodes anywhere in the tree.

Comment: This was what i hadn't consider because Add method does not tell me that it gets element classes so I thought it just get strings.

Comment: @Freshblood: `Add` uses an object as a parameter (same as the element constructor). You can add any `XObject` (that is possible to add) and any other object convertable to an `XText` (string, numbers, ... - primarily using `XmlConvert`).

Comment: My knowledge about programming is ok . i just can need to read spesific articles about xml namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create xml structure directly:

```
XElement root = new XElement("root",
    new XElement("first", "value",
        new XElement("second", "Value")));
```

Traverse the nodes using various methods like `Element`:

```
root.Element("first").Element("second").Add(new XElement("third", "Value"));
//or
root.Descendants("second").First().Add(new XElement("underTheThird", "Value"));
```

Add to any element:

```
root.Add(new XElement("underTheSecond", 456));
```

etc.

Microsoft has several documents available for reading - like the [Reference (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387101.aspx).

**Edit** - collected the info I've posted in comments:

You can do `root.Add(first);` first and then do `first.Add(second);`. The order in which you do that does not matter. The Xml document is not built like a string, it is a hierarchy of objects - you can add new nodes anywhere in the tree.

Add uses an object as a parameter (same as the element constructor). You can add any `XObject` (that is possible to add) and any other object convertable to an `XText` (string, numbers, ... - primarily using `XmlConvert`).

*Freshblood: I think that XmlLinkedNode class provide what i need.*:
You can use either the `NextNode` or the `PreviousNode` property to get the siblings and the `Parent` property to get the parent of the current node.

Although all that info is reachable through the link I have posted in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for everyone if i couldn't explain my question well.Xml classes get confused me.U you say that u can do samething with XElement i will try it. As result i tried to say that i want to navigate in xml tree and i want to add new element wherever i am in then i want to pass last added element. i was also trying LinqToXml classes.Anyway i will try what u have said. Thanks for your effort

Comment: Well, that is exactly what we described. You can save the last added element to a variable and use it later. You are asking very basic programming concepts. Get some books about programming, it will help you more than asking specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to create XML elements and then comeback and add addtional child elements. You might want you look at using the [XmLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class for this.

Using XElement you can also do this as follows

```
  XElement root = new XElement("Root");
  XElement biggest = new XElement("Biggest");
  XElement bigger = new XElement("Bigger");
  XElement another = new XElement("Another");

  root.Add(biggest);
  biggest.Add(bigger);
  biggest.Add(another);
```

Here each step adds to the hierarchy, but at each interim step the hierarchy is valid XML.

***Update:***
Based on the question in the comment I think this is what you are looking for

```
  root.Add(biggest);
  root.Element("Biggest").Add(bigger);      
  root.Element("Biggest").Add(another);
```

Comment: Can u please add bigger into biggest without over biggest reference ? I mean just using root referance

Comment: @Freshblood, I added an example of what I think you are asking for. Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: I couldn't explain my problem well. I think that XmlLinkedNode class provide what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but I found this guys' site very helpful to work with xml files.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XML_Configuration_File.aspx

If you use it, make sure you wrap all of the instances in using..found that out the hard way.